# Updating a MYSQL table based on values input in 2nd table

Tags: mysql, updating

I have a database with sports scores and standings. I have a standings table like so...

```
Team     Overall Record    Conference Record
Team1    5-0               2-0
Team2    4-1               1-1
Team3    3-2               0-2
```

And I have a results table for the games...

```
Team    Result1  Result2   Result3  Result4   Result5  Result6
Team1   W        W         W        W         W
Team2   W        L         W        W         W
Team3   W        L         L        W         W
```

Now when I add a "W" to Result6 for the next game, is there a way to have it update Team1 record to 6-0 in the standings table or if it's an "L" then change it to 5-1?

Comment: Your data structure really needs to be improved.  Storing results in different columns is not the SQLish way of storing repeating data.

Comment: Why not have Win, Loss, Total games instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have a bad table structure and I have a bad offer, too!

```
 SET @teamname := 'team1';

 SELECT @myres := concat(Result1,Result2,Result3,Result4,Result5,Result6) -- and other columns
 FROM results
 WHERE team = @teamname;

 UPDATE sports_score
 SET overal = concat(
      length(@myres)-length(replace(@myres,'W',''))
 ,'-',
      length(@myres)-length(replace(@myres,'L',''))
 )
 WHERE team = @teamname ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This way has the name "[triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html)". AFTER UPDATE seems to match your case.

Although, as others suggested, your DB design is far from being perfect.

Basically, @r0xette made an exellent suggestion: keep win, loss, draw in your "standings" table, then you can just increment appropriate column in the update made by your trigger, and you won't need to care about the previous values and go through the whole set of columns/records in "games" table to calculate your "record" pair - you'll be doing it at SELECT time, like:

```
SELECT concat( win, ' - ', loss) AS OverallRecord FROM standings WHERE team = 'team1';
```